# MySQL query which would give me all rows for appointment booking those fulfil rules mentioned below

Tags: php, mysql, appointment

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appointment` (
  `appointment_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `appointment_date` date NOT NULL,
  `appointment_time` time NOT NULL,
  `appointment_endtime` time NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `therapist_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `status` char(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'SEND' COMMENT 's=send a=accept d=decline r=reschudle',
  `is_doctor_reschedule` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`appointment_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

I am writing query like

```
SELECT therapist_id
     , appointment_time
     , appointment_endtime 
  FROM appointment 
 WHERE   (appointment_time BETWEEN '".$timee."' AND '".$end_time."' 
       OR appointment_endtime BETWEEN '".$timee."' AND '".$end_time."')
   AND therapist_id = '".$_REQUEST['therapist_id']."' 
   AND appointment_date = '".$_REQUEST['date']."' 
   AND status = 'ACCEPTED'
```

### Rules

1. if user book appointment on date : 04-11-2015 start time : 09:00:00 and End time 10:00:00 other user cannot book appointment on that time and date.
2. can't book appointment with time like date : 04-11-2015 start time : 08:30:00 and End time 09:30:00
3. can't book appointment with time like date : 04-11-2015 start time : 09:30:00 and End time 10:30:00
4. can't book appointment with time like date : 04-11-2015 start time : 08:00:00 and End time 11:00:00
5. can't book appointment with time like date : 04-11-2015 start time : 09:20:00 and End time 09:40:00

Comment: The rules seem quite arbitrary. Do you mean that a user cannot book a slot that overlaps with that of another appointment?

Comment: Yes Sir cannot book a slot that overlaps with that of another appointment.

Comment: OK, I think you need to think about how you want the user interface to work in the event that there is an overlap. For instance will there be a dropdown list of available slots, or will a user just submit their preferred dates and be advised afterwards of availability.

Comment: Also, store booking start_date_time as a single entity. Likewise for booking end_date_time.

Comment: Sir these things need to cheek when user going to fix an appointment with therapist

Comment: So, how does a question that starts with "guys I need" get two upvotes, exactly?

Comment: Note that the rule for overlaps is simply that event A *starts* before event B *ends*, AND event A *ends* after event B *starts*.

Comment: Jan Dvorak Sir i don't know that i can not write like " guys I need "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using the php variable references, this should work for you to prevent overlaps.  It appears you are trying to take a web request of certain times and therapist and querying to find if its ok or not.  Don't look for an existing appointment time between the times you are trying to add, but look for the times you are trying to add be in conflict with an existing record.

```
(   webStartTimeVar between appointment_time and appointment_endtime 
 OR webEndTimeVar between appointment_time and appointment_endtime )
```

If you get a record back from the results, there is a conflict.  This qualifies both begin or end time within, OR the entire appointment WITHIN another.  Such as one person has a 1hr appointment from say... 8am - 9am, and a new entry is trying for 8:20am - 8:40am which is totally WITHIN the other.  the web-time 8:20 is in conflict with the 8-9 period, You have a record, you have the conflict.  Don't allow adding the appointment.

Now, the outlyer...  Doing the reverse.  if an existing appointment is from 8:20-8:40, and a new appointment is from 8am - 9am.  Then you need an outer edge test

```
(   webStartTimeVar <= appointment_time AND webEndTimeVar >= appointment_endtime )
```

So your most complete query would be.

```
(   webStartTimeVar between appointment_time and appointment_endtime 
 OR webEndTimeVar between appointment_time and appointment_endtime )
 OR ( webStartTimeVar <= appointment_time AND webEndTimeVar >= appointment_endtime )
)
```

I would also have a compound index to help optimize your query on

( status, appointment_date, therapist_id )

and for a covering index, you could extend even more by adding the start/end appointment times, but that might be overkill based on number of appointments that would be in a given day for a single therapist.

Comment: Thank you Sir thank you very much you hit the BULLS EYE. i spent my whole day for this issue. Once again Thanks

Comment: @jitendraparmar, glad it worked.  Sometimes you need to look at things in a REVERSE position and take the logical NOT from it.  This is such a similar case. Not looking for an appointment in your times, but your times within an existing appointment, then edged it out.